# C++ COM (non MFC) calling method with pointer argument

Tags: c++, pointers, com

I'm trying to reproduce a COM client in c++ in the non MFC way. I'm able to connect to the com interface and call some methods that require simple values as parameter, but I'm not able to call a method with a pointer as argument, the function is this:

```
short sProdGetCurrentMachineType(short* p_psMachineType)
```

and in the `short` variable pointed by `p_psMachineType` will be stored the result value.

I tried this:

```
DISPID dispid; //omitted for brevity, i get it from QueryInterface() on the com

VARIANT pVarResult;
EXCEPINFO pExcepInfo;
unsigned int* puArgErr = 0;
DISPPARAMS dispparams{}; 
VARIANTARG rgvarg[1];
short *p_psMachineType;
 

rgvarg[0].vt = VT_I2;
rgvarg[0].piVal = p_psMachineType;
dispparams.rgvarg = rgvarg;
dispparams.cArgs = 1;
dispparams.cNamedArgs = 0;

hresult = (*pDisp)->Invoke(
            dispid,
            IID_NULL,
            LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT,
            DISPATCH_METHOD,
            &dispparams, &pVarResult, &pExcepInfo, puArgErr
        );
```

but I get a `TYPE_MISMATCH ERROR`..

Instead I saw that using it as named argument I don't get error in the call but the pointer value is not populated, but i cannot find any example of pointers passed as named arguments.

Does anybody know how to handle it?

Comment: Have you tried VT_I2 | VT_BYREF? It works for me (inprocess, same apartment) but may depend on your exact implementation details (tlb, etc.). Also make sure you initialize pExcepInfo and pvarResult properly (or pass NULL)

Comment: It worked! I think that's the only option i didn't tried.. thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Simon Mourier said the correct parameter to set on the rgvarg array was  VT_I2 | VT_BYREF instead of  VT_I2

Answer (score 0):

As you say yourself, "in the short variable pointed by p_psMachineType will be stored the result value", so you need to pass it a valid pointer to an existing `short`.

```
short psMachineType;
// ...
rgvarg[0].piVal = &psMachineType;
```

Comment: I still get a TYPE_MISMATCH error and the psMachineType value is not populated

Comment: Yes, `VT_I2` designates `short`not `short*`. I *think* you want `VT_PTR`; study the documentation to be sure. (Of course the value isn't populated if the call fails.)

Comment: Tried, i get a BAD_VAR_TYPE error.. I left it as VT_I2 beacause in a similar project using the same COM server but with MFC they call the InvokeHelper using VT_I2 type, and it works